# How to make C++ menu text

Tags: c++, text, menu

I'm making a text based adventure game. I want to have the game name (marooned) in large or made out of lines. How can I do this?

An example of what I want is something like this:

> ╔═╗╔═╗───╔╗────────╔╗────╔╗─╔╗──╔╗╔╗────╔═══╦╗
>   ║║╚╝║║───║║────────║║────║║─║║──║║║║────╚╗╔╗║║
>   ║╔╗╔╗╠══╦╣║╔╦══╦╗─╔╣║╔══╗║╚═╝╠══╣║║║╔══╗─║║║║╚═╦══╦══╦══╗*
>   ║║║║║║╔╗╠╣╚╝╣╔╗║║─║║║║╔╗║║╔═╗║║═╣║║║║╔╗║─║║║║╔╗║╔╗║╔╗║║═╣
>   ║║║║║║╔╗║║╔╗╣╔╗║╚═╝║╚╣╔╗║║║─║║║═╣╚╣╚╣╔╗║╔╝╚╝║║║║╚╝║╚╝║║═╣
>   ╚╝╚╝╚╩╝╚╩╩╝╚╩╝╚╩═╗╔╩═╩╝╚╝╚╝─╚╩══╩═╩═╩╝╚╝╚═══╩╝╚╩══╣╔═╩══╝
>   ───────────────╔═╝║───────────────────────────────║║
>   ───────────────╚══╝───────────────────────────────╚╝

but more visible. And also when this is compiled it comes out in `?`'s.  So I need the text to be compiler friendly.

Comment: Ive tried using various lines such as _ and | but the way im doing it looks unbelievably stupid.

Comment: You could create char array filled with the ascii code of every char and print the char array. This way they'll be converted correctly. Here is a ascii code table: http://www.asciitable.com/index/extend.gif

Comment: @MatteoItalia Im on windows 7.

Comment: Windows uses the so-called OEM codepage for the console, so you either specify your text directly in this CP (which may be a problem, since it can change from computer to computer), either store the text in Unicode format and print it to cout only after an appropriate encoding conversion. A better alternative may be storing the text in Unicode (UTF-16 wide strings) and using `wcout` to output them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, go with wide string literals:

```
wchar_t * titleStr= L"╔═╗╔═╗───╔╗────────╔╗────╔╗─╔╗──╔╗╔╗────╔═══╦╗\n"
                    L"║║╚╝║║───║║────────║║────║║─║║──║║║║────╚╗╔╗║║\n"
                    L"║╔╗╔╗╠══╦╣║╔╦══╦╗─╔╣║╔══╗║╚═╝╠══╣║║║╔══╗─║║║║╚═╦══╦══╦══╗*\n"
                    L"║║║║║║╔╗╠╣╚╝╣╔╗║║─║║║║╔╗║║╔═╗║║═╣║║║║╔╗║─║║║║╔╗║╔╗║╔╗║║═╣ \n"
                    L"║║║║║║╔╗║║╔╗╣╔╗║╚═╝║╚╣╔╗║║║─║║║═╣╚╣╚╣╔╗║╔╝╚╝║║║║╚╝║╚╝║║═╣ \n"
                    L"╚╝╚╝╚╩╝╚╩╩╝╚╩╝╚╩═╗╔╩═╩╝╚╝╚╝─╚╩══╩═╩═╩╝╚╝╚═══╩╝╚╩══╣╔═╩══╝ \n"
                    L"───────────────╔═╝║───────────────────────────────║║ \n"
                    L"───────────────╚══╝───────────────────────────────╚╝\n"
std::wcout<<titleStr;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this.

The easiest way is to cout (char)<[ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character code here> which will allow you to print those border characters instead of underscores and dashes.

A list of [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters and their codes is at http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/ascii/.

You could also try dumping all that text in separate text file, read and parse the file, and then print it to the console.

Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::ifstream reader("art.txt"); //Load the text
    std::string art = parseart(reader); //Parse the file
    std::cout << art << std::endl; //Print

    reader.close();
    return 0;
}

std::string parseart(std::ifstream& File) {
   std::string parsedfile;

   if(File) {
       while(File.good()) {
           std::string tmpline;
           std::getline(File, tmpline);
           tmpline += "\n";

           parsedfile += tmpline;
       }
       return parsedfile;
   } else {
       //Error
   }
```